# How to use Pygame to do crib dragging

Tags: one-time-pad

I have two files ctext0 and ctext1 that are byte files and they are encoded using the same one time pad, so I tried to write a pygame program to allow me to use crib-dragging to figure out some words like so:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

file_size1 = os.path.getsize('ctext0')
file_size2 = os.path.getsize('ctext1')

pygame.init()

# Load the byte files
with open('ctext0', 'rb') as f0:
    ctext0 = f0.read()

with open('ctext1', 'rb') as f1:
    ctext1 = f1.read()

# Create the window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


# Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Draw the byte files
    image0 = pygame.image.frombuffer(ctext0, (file_size1 // 3, file_size1 // 3), 'RGB', False)
    image1 = pygame.image.frombuffer(ctext1, (file_size2 // 3, file_size2 // 3), 'RGB', False)
    window.blit(image0, (0, 0))
    window.blit(image1, (100, 0))

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.update()
```

However this program just opens a black screen and immediately exits the program. With the following printed to the terminal:
pygame 2.5.0 (SDL 2.28.0, Python 3.11.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Comment: Normally I would have migrated this question to SO, but due to the moderator strike we were not able to (see side bar / meta). If you want I can still migrate, but please let me know if this is still required after so long.